# Watch in Directive changing Model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Hello I need some help I tried creating a directive which watches the model of an input field if that model changes it should check for special Characters if they are there the model gets parsed and it should return the parsed value.

Now all of that is working fine the value of the input field changed and is correct but it seems only the value changed while the model is still as it was not parsed.

My Html

```
<input type="text" name="bestellnummer" ng-model="we.bestellnummer" required parse/>
```

And My Directive

```
.directive('parse', function ($timeout, Ls, $window) {

return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (Val) {
            //console.log(Val)
            if (Val != undefined) {
                if ((Val.toString()).indexOf('?') != -1 && (Val.toString()).indexOf('!') != -1) {
                    Val = Val.slice(0, -1);
                    scope.code = new Gs1Parser.Parse(Val);
                    //console.log(scope.code);
                    if (scope.code != undefined && scope.code[0].Key != 'invalid') {

                        var ParsedVal = scope.code[0].Key;
                        scope.code = undefined;                     
                        $window.Gs1Parser.returnedValue = [];
                        //try with ngModel
                        ngModel.$modelValue = ParsedVal;
                        //element[0].value = ParsedVal;
                       //scope.ab.abNr = ParsedVal;
                    } else if (scope.code[0].Key == 'invalid') {
                        Val = Val.slice(1);
                        //element[0].value = Val;
                        //scope.ab.abNr = Val;
                    }
                }
            }
        })                   
    }
}
```

})

So basically the the user enters ?12345! the Parser changes this to 345 and this should be the new model. At the moment the value is 345 but as soon as I send the Data the modelvale (?12345!) is sent.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: why u cant use ng-change?

Comment: id prefer it to be in a seperate directive because I have multiple independent modules and with ng-change I would have to take this logic into a controller but if i have no other choice i guess ng-change could be a possibility

Comment: You should not change DOM value, change model instead. Require ngModel in directive and change its value.

Comment: I updated my answer with the changes cant quite get it to work i added the require and the I change it like this ngModel.$modelValue = ParsedVal

Comment: I missed smth, you do not need require ngModel: http://plnkr.co/edit/qLFCqd56o9rbwaXgzE2k?p=preview

Comment: Wow this worked like a charm you can create an answer so i can upvote it if u like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change scope value, like:

```
$parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, Val);
```

(simple `scope[attrs.ngModel]=Val` wont work for i.e. 'model.value' only for simple 'value')
You should be careful thow since changing this value will trigger your watch once again.